# Counting number of rows matching criteria between two dates

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to query a postgres db table for a count of rows matching some criteria between a time range. I am using the sequelize orm with nodejs.
In my controller method i have a query

```
var query = 'SELECT o.ordered_at, COUNT(o.id) AS order_count FROM "Orders" o WHERE status = :status AND o.ordered_at >= :lower_limit AND o.ordered_at <= :upper_limit GROUP BY o.id ORDER BY o.ordered_at DESC';

      models.sequelize.query(query, queryOptions).
      then(function (orders) {
        res.status(200).json(response);
      }).
      catch(function (err) {
        logger.error(err);
        res.status(500).json(err.message);
      })
```

this yields a response like this

```
[
  {
    "ordered_at": "2016-12-10T16:05:46.525Z",
    "order_count": "1"
  },
  {
    "ordered_at": "2016-12-10T16:03:46.429Z",
    "order_count": "1"
  },
  {
    "ordered_at": "2016-12-10T16:01:46.440Z",
    "order_count": "1"
  },
  {
    "ordered_at": "2016-12-05T12:20:18.714Z",
    "order_count": "1"
  },
  {
    "ordered_at": "2016-12-05T12:18:18.650Z",
    "order_count": "1"
  },
  {
    "ordered_at": "2016-12-03T12:16:18.658Z",
    "order_count": "1"
  }
]
```

You can see the query returns the order_count for each row instead of for each order, so i am try to transform the data here

```
  var data = [],
      lower_time_limit = t(new Date());

  var range = _.range(30),
      month_lower_limit = t(lower_time_limit).subtract(1, 'M').startOf('day');

  var lower_limit,
      limit,
      upper_limit;

  _.forEach(range, function (day, key) {
      limit = t(month_lower_limit);
      lower_limit = t(limit.add(day, 'd'));
      upper_limit = t(limit.add(1, 'd'));

      _.forEach(orders, function (order, index) {
        var count = 0;
        if (t(order.ordered_at).isBetween(lower_limit, upper_limit, 'second', '[)')) {
          var orderCount = count + parseInt(order.order_count);
          data.push({date: lower_limit, count: orderCount})
        }
      });
  });

  return data;
```

I know am missing something, just can't figure it out.

Comment: What you want isn't clear but it looks like it can, and should, be a simple SQL problem that shouldn't be fixed by postprocessing but with a correct SQL query.

Comment: @DenysSéguret i am trying to get a count of rows that have a particular value for the status field and lie between two dates. My query provides me with a count for each row rather than each day, so i am trying to postprocessing the result and aggregate the data for each day and then each hour depending on the date range provided.

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY o.id` will produce one group (i.e. one row in the output) per `o.id`. You want one group for all matching rows, which is what you get if you omit the `GROUP BY` entirely.

Including `o.ordered_at` in your output doesn't make a whole lot of sense; if you're aggregating multiple matching rows into a single output record, it's not clear whose `ordered_at` time you'd be expecting to see.

And once you've got one row of output, an `ORDER BY` won't do you much good.

With all of that in mind:

```
SELECT COUNT(o.id) AS order_count
FROM "Orders" o
WHERE status = :status
  AND o.ordered_at >= :lower_limit
  AND o.ordered_at <= :upper_limit
```